# Animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want to create a page which clicking on it open a div from the right of the page. The opening done by animation.
when i open a div from right i want that the div will be expanded and all by animation,
i write

```
<button onclick="Animation();">click</button>

<Div> 
    <Table style="float:right">
        <tr>
            <td> 
                <div id="dummy" style="height:0"> 
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>
                <div>
                list view 1
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                list view 2
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                list view 3
                </div>
            </td>

             <td> 
                <div id="dummy1">right </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </Table>
</div>

  function Animation() {

            var right_div = jQuery("#dummy1");
            right_div.first().addClass("bounceInRight");
        }

     .bounceInRight 
{
 width:80px;
    background:yellow;
     -webkit-animation: bounceInRight 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: bounceInRight 5s;
}


   @-webkit-keyframes bounceInRight {
  0%, 60%, 75%, 90%, 100% {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(3000px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(3000px, 0, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-25px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-25px, 0, 0);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

but first the div is expanded and the the animation is act, how can i make it simultaneity? that the div will be bigger as part as the animation

Comment: like this --> http://jsbin.com/haqigiliroze/1/edit

Comment: not exactly, if you have two divs one enter from right and make the current one to be smaller (with an animation simultaneity) .

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to use foundation. It is a great framework and I think it provides what you are looking for along with other tools that I find to be extremely useful.

If you don't want to use a framework, that is perfectly understandable, though I'd recommend Foundation.

Take a look at what it has to offer, it will make web designing much more simpler :)